# Karaf feature:install does nothing

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I've downloaded ServiceMix 7.0.1 and followed the documentation. I need to install Camel features using:

```
karaf@root>feature:install camel-sql
```

But when I do that nothing happens. There's no response until I hit ctrl-c. The log file doesn't help either.

```
2020-03-25 14:13:25,709 | INFO  | Thread-16        | FeaturesServiceImpl              
   | 8 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.9 | Adding features: camel-sql/[2.24.2,2.24.2]
```

And the online documentation is sparse to say the least.

**Update**

Using -v -t gives the below output, but still nothing thereafter:

```
karaf@root>feature:install -v -t camel-sql
Adding features: camel-sql/[2.24.2,2.24.2]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to update Maven configuration in `etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` in your ServiceMIX 7.0.1 installation. Change:

```
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories= \
    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2@id=central, \
    http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release@id=spring.ebr.release, \
    http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external@id=spring.ebr.external, \
    http://zodiac.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release@id=gemini, \
    http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group@id=apache@snapshots@noreleases, \
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots@id=sonatype.snapshots.deploy@snapshots@noreleases, \
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ops4j-snapshots@id=ops4j.sonatype.snapshots.deploy@snapshots@noreleases
```

to:

```
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories= \
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2@id=central, \
    http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release@id=spring.ebr.release, \
    http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external@id=spring.ebr.external, \
    http://zodiac.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release@id=gemini, \
    http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group@id=apache@snapshots@noreleases, \
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots@id=sonatype.snapshots.deploy@snapshots@noreleases, \
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ops4j-snapshots@id=ops4j.sonatype.snapshots.deploy@snapshots@noreleases
```

repo1.maven.org no longer allows access using `http`. `https` is required.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: What is the output of `feature:install -t -v camel-sql` then? I saw in logs clear information that Maven Central returns `501 HTTPS Required`.

Comment: Just a heads up that Apache ServiceMix is a dead project and is going to the attic. I suggest to switch to Apache Karaf and then install Camel. Then you have an active maintained project to use as platform.

Comment: I had exactly this problem (with camel-servlet in my case), and this solution fixed it for me, though I also did a "feature:repo-refresh".

(Also: yeah, I'll work on converting our org from ServiceMix to Karaf, but that's a longer-term thing than the problem I was trying to solve today.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try `bundle:install mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-sql/2.24.2`